# Is there an equivalent of Ctrl-R but for single arguments, rather than whole commands (zsh)?

Tags: zsh

I use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>R</kbd> constantly to search for previous commands that I've run and then edit them. I also regularly use <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>.</kbd> to cycle through the last argument of previous commands. I'd like to have something that does a bit of both.

Is there a way to search through individual arguments of previous commands and insert them in the current command? For example:

```
$ run_pipeline --arg1 blah --arg2 blah some/long/path some/other/long/path
... run many other commands ...
$ ls -l <a keystroke that will let me bring up some/long/path>
```

Ideally I'd like this to be interactive ala <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>R</kbd> / <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>S</kbd>, so that I can preview what I'll be inserting and edit my search before inserting the argument.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the following zle widget you should get the *near* your desired behavior:

```
fzf-last-word-widget() {
  local POSITION RECALL_ARGUMENT
  if [[ ! -z $NUMERIC ]]; then
    POSITION=-${NUMERIC}
  else
    POSITION=-1
  fi

  histlist=$(
    for histitem ("${(@f)$(fc -l 1)}") {
      histwords=(${(z)histitem})
      print -- $histwords[$POSITION]
    }
  )
  RECALL_ARGUMENT=$(print $histlist | fzf --tac +s -e)
  if [[ ! -z $RECALL_ARGUMENT ]]; then
    LBUFFER="${LBUFFER}${(q)RECALL_ARGUMENT}"
    zle redisplay
  fi
}
zle -N        fzf-last-word-widget
bindkey '^Xr' fzf-last-word-widget
```

- I use [`fzf`](https://github.com/junegunn/fzf) to present a nice interactive list of the last arguments of the history. So this needs to be installed.
- The widget respects a *numeric argument* to pick also the second last, third last, etc. argument. Please check `man zshzle` for *numeric argument* how to enter this on the command line.
- In the example the widget is bound to `CTRL-X R`.

---

Now, to explain better how the widget works, lets tear it apart:

- *zle* is the *zsh line editor* which is responsible for your interactive experience at the prompt (comparable to *readline* in *bash*).
- A zle widget is just a special shell function, which gets introduced to zle via `zle -N fzf-last-word-widget` and then can be bound to a key sequence like any built-in widget (`bindkey '^Xr' fzf-last-word-widget`).
- You can pass a *numeric argument* to a widget; quoting from `man zshzle`

  > This can by default be entered in emacs mode by holding
  > the alt key and typing a number, or pressing escape before each digit, and in vi command mode by typing the  number  be‐
  > fore  entering  a  command.

This numeric argument is passed to the widget in the variable `$NUMERIC` and can be used therein.

- This is with what the first code block deals, it checks if an numeric argument was passed by checking if `$NUMERIC` does not equal to an empty string (`! -z $NUMERIC`). If it's present, its inverse is stored in a local variable (`local POSITION`) named `$POSITION`, otherwise `$POSITION` defaults to -1.
- There are a number of special variables available inside zle, some of which can be altered; see *USER-DEFINED WIDGETS* in `man zshzle`. Relevant here is `$LBUFFER` which holds the portion of your entered command line *left* to the cursor (hence the `L` in its name; there is also `$RBUFFER`). If you edit it the cursor moves accordingly, just after the complete buffer (there is also `$BUFFER`) is redrawn by `zle redisplay`. Here I append the (local) string `$RECALL_ARGUMENT` to `$LBUFFER`, but let *zsh* take care of quoting by using the `(q)` *expansion flag* (see `man zshexpn`) so that an argument like `path with spaces/foobar` will end up as `path\ with\ spaces/foobar`. (There is a check if `$RECALL_ARGUMENT` is empty, e.g. when you abort `fzf`. Otherwise you end up with two single quotes `''` on you command line.)
- The task is now reduced to build $RECALL_ARGUMENT to your wishes. As mentioned, I used [`fzf`](https://github.com/junegunn/fzf) to present a nice interactive list where you can easily search and pick what you want. `fzf` reads from *stdin* and writes your pick to *stdout*. The arguments disable sorting of the list (`+s`), reverse the list (`--tac`, which I personally like better) and enable exact match (`-e`). To make it more readable I resisted to write an one-liner, so the input to `fzf` is constructed separately in the array `$histlist`. So we pass `$histlist` to `fzf` via pipe and read the output into `$RECALL_ARGUMENT` by command substitution `$()`.
- We want the history, so we get it from the first line onward via `fc -l 1`, do a splitting on newlines into an array (expansion flags `(@f)`) and loop over each line with `for`. We do need to wrap `"${(@f)$(fc -l 1)}"` in quotes to prevent a splitting on white spaces.
- Now `$histline` contains a line from the history like e.g.     `1  echo foo`. This line we split into *shell words* via `(z)` expansion flag. *shell word* means that `echo foo\ bar` is split only into `echo` & `foo\ bar` and not into `echo`, `foo\` & `bar` and store the results into `$histwords`; this should be an array, that's why the values are wrapped with braces `(...)`.
- After the splitting we pick the shell words we want to have, in the example the `$POSITION`*th* one (as `$POSITION` is negative it counts from the back), and print it out. (As you want to have all arguments to pick from separately you can use your command `printf '%s\n' "${histwords[@]:1}"` or alternatively use `print -l -- $histwords[2,-1]` which should be equal.)
- All printed strings are gathered in the array `$histlist` which then is passed to `fzf` as explained above.

Comment: This is great! If you find the time I'd love to hear more about how it works. My one issue is that this seems to search only the arguments in a specific position. I understand that I can change which position with a numeric argument. But really I'd just like to search _all_ arguments, regardless of their position.

Comment: @danvk: Thanks! Do you mean, _search_ all arguments, but then _pick_ only the last?

Comment: my comment about `ALT-.` may have been misleading, I really don't care about position at all. I'd like to search over all arguments and pick the same argument that I match. I changed the `print` in your widget to `printf '%s\n' "${histwords[@]:1}"` and it seems to do what I want. Does that make sense?

Comment: @danvk: I'm glad that you figured it out yourself how to modify the widget. However, I also added some (hopefully not too confusing) explanations to my answer.